# How to show custom dialog at the top center of the screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I am going to show a custom dialog at the top center of the screen.

I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxPMr.png) .

How can I accomplish this? Default position of Dialog is center of the screen.

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Align and Material widget. (`Alignment.topCenter`) i.e

```
void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context, String message) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext cxt) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.green,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Image.asset("assets/close.png")),
                        SizedBox(width: 16),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            message,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```